# What am I doing wrong? wcf & entity-framework

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, poco, wcf-data-services

I just came across `WCF` today and started learning it. However, once I tried to combine it with the `EntityFramework` it stopped working. I created a entity model for my database `dtcinvoicerdb`, turned off code generation and wrote the `Entity/ObjectContext` classes myself. The service is supposed to fetch all the `Employees` from the database.

Everything works fine, the project compiles and the WcfTestClient opens up, but when I try to Invoke the `GetEmployees()` operation I get the following exception:

```
Mapping and metadata information could not be found for EntityType 'DtcInvoicerDbModel.Employee'.
```

I know there's a lot of code below, but it's all pretty basic so bear with me.

[entity image and model properties http://img716.imageshack.us/img716/1397/wcf.png](http://img716.imageshack.us/img716/1397/wcf.png)

**/Entities/DtcInvoicerDbContext.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.Data.Objects;

using DtcInvoicerDbModel;

namespace DtcInvoicerServiceLibrary
{
    public class DtcInvoicerDbContext:ObjectContext
    {
        public DtcInvoicerDbContext():base("name=DtcInvoicerDbEntities", "DtcInvoicerDbEntities")
        {
        }

        #region public ObjectSet<Employee> Employees;
        private ObjectSet<Employee> _Employees;
        public ObjectSet<Employee> Employees
        {
            get
            {
                return (_Employees == null) ? (_Employees = base.CreateObjectSet<Employee>("Employees")) : _Employees;
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

**/Entities/Employee.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace DtcInvoicerDbModel
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Employee
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Username { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime EmployeeSince { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**/IDtcInvoicerServicer.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.ServiceModel;

using DtcInvoicerDbModel;

namespace DtcInvoicerServiceLibrary
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IDtcInvoicerService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        List<Employee> GetEmployees();
    }
}
```

**/DtcInvoicerService.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.ServiceModel;

using DtcInvoicerDbModel;

namespace DtcInvoicerServiceLibrary
{
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single, IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true)]
    public class DtcInvoicerService:IDtcInvoicerService
    {
        private DtcInvoicerDbContext db = new DtcInvoicerDbContext();

        public List<Employee> GetEmployees()
        {
            return db.Employees.Where(x => x.ID > 0).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this doesn't answer your question, but with your service, have you considered using [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106) instead?  Your service is returning your entities to your client -- WCF Data Services can provide that for you and also give your client the ability to use LINQ queries to filter and/or project your results.

You could add a WCF Data Service item (InvoicerService.svc) to your project and set up the service class like so:

```
public class InvoicerService : DataService<DtcInvoicerDbEntities>
{
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Employees", EntitySetRights.AllRead);

        config.SetEntitySetPageSize("*", 25);
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
    }
}
```

You could then access your employees via a GET request using the URL:

```
http://server:port/InvoicerService.svc/Employees?$filter=ID gt 0
```

Again, not the answer to your question, but perhaps an alternative.  Just thought I'd add it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, thanks for your effort. I actually haven't considered that (mostly because I don't know anything about it). I'm checking out that link your gave me, I'm sure it will help or teach me something new at the very least. Thanks again! :)

Comment: No problem.  Let me know if you have other questions.  I'm a fan of WCF Data Services, and I don't think it gets the attention it should.  :)

Comment: I actually did have a question. My plan is to create a WCF service that gets data from the database, and serves it to the clients where it's stored in some sort of `Dictionary/Collection` per EntityType. The client application messes around with the entities and then sends the data back to the Service which commits the change to the database **AND** sends the updated/changed objects to *all* of the connected clients and replaces the older version of itself in the collection. And then there's other details like locking an object when it's being edited by a client. With that said

Comment: ... my question is, do you think I'm going down the correct path here (with a WcfService, should I consider DataServices), do you have any other links that might help my project? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Honestly, if that's what you're trying to do, you may want to consider Data Services.  The HTTP verbs help describe what you're trying to do (POST=insert, PUT=update, etc.), and there are client libraries for various platforms to help with that.  Check out http://www.odata.org/developers/odata-sdk for various client libraries; check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668772%28VS.100%29.aspx for a reference on various .NET WCF Data Service operations for client apps.  Hope this helps!!

Comment: Hey, that look good. I think it's the right path to take because I will eventually be consuming the data from .NET (invoicing software) and PHP (company website). Anyways, thanks again for the help!

Comment: Since it's just HTTP rest, it doesn't matter what your client is...so it sounds like a good alternative.  Glad I could help.  Good luck!!

Answer (score 2):

Ahh got it to work after some more searching on stackoverflow and comparing with the generated code.

**Errors:** I was missing a property `IsActive`, and I didn't add Edm attributes to the class and it's properties.

For anyone that comes across the same problem, remember to set the EdmScalarProperty (or other property type) attribute on all your properties, and don't forget to set which property acts as the `EntityKey` (e.g. ID).

Here's what my `Employee` class looks like now, and it works.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

[assembly: EdmSchemaAttribute()]
namespace DtcInvoicerDbModel
{
    [EdmEntityType(NamespaceName="DtcInvoicerDbModel", Name="Employee")]
    [DataContract(IsReference=true)]
    public class Employee
    {
        [DataMember]
        [EdmScalarProperty(EntityKeyProperty = true, IsNullable = false)]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [EdmScalarProperty(EntityKeyProperty = false, IsNullable = false)]
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [EdmScalarProperty(EntityKeyProperty = false, IsNullable = false)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [EdmScalarProperty(EntityKeyProperty = false, IsNullable = false)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [EdmScalarProperty(EntityKeyProperty = false, IsNullable = false)]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [EdmScalarProperty(EntityKeyProperty = false, IsNullable = false)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [EdmScalarProperty(EntityKeyProperty = false, IsNullable = true)]
        public DateTime? EmployeeSince { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: nice to see you got it working ... but i think i would have taken daves approach :)